# Adding Light in Eevee is slowing down Blender

Tags: system

I made a simple city project, just in the blocking phase. I added street 4 street lamps with emission shader (in eevee). Now I have to add area-lights to illuminate the scene. But the moment i add an area-light to the 4th lamp my Blender starts freezing. Why is this happening? Before adding the 4th light Blender is absolutely fine. It seems Blender is hitting some bottleneck with the 4th light? Can anyone shed some light on this and make it possible for me to move further with the proejct?

Comment: If your issue is very project specific, you should provide a (minimal) blend file so it could be looked at.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In Render-Properties > Shadows, I had High Bit Depth enabled. Turning it off solved the problem.